# How to Get the Text of SQL Statement in a Trigger

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Do you know how to obtain the text of sql statement inside a trigger?

Thanks

Comment: Hmm, have you tried creating a string function secure_update.
Inside you count the numbers of table1 inside the string. 
Then count the number of where clauses using the same logic. 
Now if # of Where clauses >= # of table1 then return true, else false.

Comment: Can flag have value other than 1 for example where flag=0

Comment: If where clause has to have flag='1' then in trigger we can stop update in case flag <> '1'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to be the bearer of sad tidings, but I don't believe you can do that. No triggering event I'm aware of has visibility on the SQL statement text. The triggering events supported by Oracle (11g) are:

- An INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statement on a specific table (or view, in some cases)
- A CREATE, ALTER, or DROP statement on any schema object
- A database startup or instance shutdown
- A specific error message or any error message
- A user logon or logoff

None of these, as far as I'm aware, have access to the text of the SQL statement. [Docs here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e10766/tdddg_triggers.htm)